# Component local state not updating with react custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just starting to use react hooks and I'm having some issues when using custom hooks. It's probably lack of understanding but here's what I'm attempting

My Custom hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

export const useValidateContent = initState => {
    const[valid, setValid] = useState(initState)
    const[errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null)

    const validate = () => {
      // Update component state to test
      setValid(false)
      setErrorMsg('Some error found')
    }

    return [valid, validate, errorMsg]

}
```

My parent container which uses the custom hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useValidateContent } from './hooks/useValidateContent'


export default function ParentComp () {

    const [contentIsValid, validate, contentError] = useValidateContent(true)

    const initValidate = () => {
        // values before running validate
        console.log('valid', contentIsValid)
        console.log('error', contentError)
        validate()
        // values after running validate
        console.log('valid', contentIsValid)
        console.log('error', contentError)
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onclick={initValidate} />
      </div>
    )
}
```

What I expected to be consoled here was:

> valid true 
> error null
> valid false
> error Some error found

Instead what I see is:

> valid true 
> error null
> valid true 
> error null

It seems like the hook is not updating the local state. Why is this? Even when I try to console those values inside the hook component I get the same thing.  I cannot figure out why this is. Am I using custom hooks wrong?

Comment: Updating state with hooks is asynchronous just like `setState` in a class component is, and since the state is not mutated `contentIsValid` and `contentError` will still refer to the stale old state and not the new state.

Comment: @Tholle I don't quite follow. I though the `setValid` and `setErrorMsg` were supposed to mutate the state.

Comment: It updates the state, but it doesn't update it in place like e.g. using the `push` method on an array does. The values will be updated in the next render.

Comment: @Tholle ahh, that makes so much more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating state with hooks is asynchronous just like `setState` in a class component is, and since the state is not mutated `contentIsValid` and `contentError` will still refer to the stale old state and not the new state.

If you render your state variables you will see that your code works as expected.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const useValidateContent = initState => {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(initState);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");

  const validate = () => {
    setValid(false);
    setErrorMsg("Some error found");
  };

  return [valid, validate, errorMsg];
};

function ParentComp() {
  const [contentIsValid, validate, contentError] = useValidateContent(true);

  const initValidate = () => {
    // values before running validate
    console.log("valid", contentIsValid);
    console.log("error", contentError);
    validate();
    // values after running validate
    console.log("valid", contentIsValid);
    console.log("error", contentError);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={initValidate}>initValidate</button>
      contentIsValid: {contentIsValid.toString()}, contentError: {contentError}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

valid state is set when you called validate() function
and since the custom hook return valid state value to the component you use it at, you can directly use valid state.

The problem is, when you called validate() and "valid" got its state changed, but our component needs to tell when valid gets a value assign render our component. So in react functional compoennts we can simply put "valid" as a dependency for useEffect. then whenever valid gets state it will call a re render for our component.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32599197)